# Compilation issues with Cmake and Intel IPP under Ubuntu

Tags: c++, linux, ubuntu, cmake, intel-ipp

The issue is that I have a source  which includes `ipps.h` and this code I'm able to compile into a `test.so` file without issues.

The problem starts when I have a Qt example which requires this built test.so file, I get the following messages from the compiler:

> /home/antti/test.so: undefined reference to 'ippsFilterMedianGetBufferSize'
>   /home/antti/test.so: undefined reference to 'ippsFilterMedian_32f'

In my `CMakeLists.txt` for compiling the `test.so`, I have the following lines in the end of the file:

```
add_library(libippcore SHARED IMPORTED)
 set_property(TARGET libippcore PROPERTY IMPORTED_IMPLIB "/opt/intel/compilers_and_libraries_2018.3.222/linux/ipp/lib/ia32_lin/libippcode.so")
```

Is this a linker problem or what is causing the issue? And how to solve it properly? The strange thing is that the Qt example is built with its own `CMakeLists.txt` but I don't see any reference in it to the `test.so` file even though it clearly includes it somehow.

Answer (score 0):

The 'ippsFilterMedian_32f' function is in 'libipps.so' library. That is signal processing library.

So, you need to add libipps (along with libippcore) to your cmake file.
Let's look what happens after you successfully built test.so.

Regards,
Sergey